# Mongo Aggregation $subtract : Always gives null result for two non empty dates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I want to get a list of employees in a sequence of their work anniversaries.
joiningDate is available in employee records.
In this query, first aniversaryDate is calculated for this year and then trying to find the difference between today's date and anniversary date. But `$subtract` return false for all sets of records.

```
db.employees.aggregate([{
    "$match": { "deleted": false }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "id": 1, "firstName": 1, "lastName": 1, "empId": 1, "joiningDate": 1,
        "aniversaryDate":
            {
                "$dateFromParts":
                    {
                        "year": { "$year": "$$NOW" },
                        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$joiningDate" },
                        "month": { "$month": "$joiningDate" }
                    }
            },
        "dateDifference":
            { "$subtract": ["$aniversaryDate", "$$NOW"] }


    }
}, { "$sort": { "dateDifference": 1 } }]);
```

Result gives array of such objects:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61a4bf6b5362437b668db2b5"),
    "empId" : "1",
    "firstName" : "Olive",
    "lastName" : "Gunter",
    "joiningDate" : ISODate("2021-10-03T16:16:58.997+05:30"),
    "aniversaryDate" : ISODate("2021-10-03T05:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "dayssince" : null,
    "dateDifference" : null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another `$project` stage to get `aniversaryDate` which is generated from the previous `$project` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "deleted": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": 1,
      "lastName": 1,
      "empId": 1,
      "joiningDate": 1,
      "aniversaryDate": {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            "$year": "$$NOW"
          },
          "day": {
            "$dayOfMonth": "$joiningDate"
          },
          "month": {
            "$month": "$joiningDate"
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "dateDifference": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$aniversaryDate",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "dateDifference": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qnsse7CD3Rd)

---

If you are using MongoDB version 5, you can replace with [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#-datediff--aggregation-).

```
{
  $project: {
    "dateDifference": {
      "$dateDiff": {
        "startDate": "$aniversaryDate",
        "endDate": "$$NOW",
        "unit": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (with `$dateDiff`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PRm6PBX0kMR)

Comment: I cant update mongo version, so I am going with $subtract